# Android App internet access not working on AT&T network

Tags: android, att

I've created and deployed an android app on to the Google play store. Throughout the entire process of developing the app I never ran into any issues with connecting to my online database. Now that I've launched it on the play store I've started having some friends getting issues with it working. After a few days of banging my head against the wall I figured out that they are all on AT&T network. If they connect to a network that isn't AT&T the app works with no issues. Basically it is just blocking the app from using the internet to connect to my database. Has anyone heard of an issue like this? Or have any solutions to get it working correctly on AT&T?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your database/server in a web browser in that AT& T network. It may not be blocking your app, but may be issue in accessing your server via AT&T network, which may be caused because of many reasons like some offensive words etc(just a possibility only)

Comment: Tried to go to the web server from a friends phone in the browser and it won't connect to it.. Just times out. Works fine on mine though.. Which is Verizon

Comment: Then nothing to worry about your code. its your server. so debug on the server side in AT&T network.